# Use sed or awk to replace text between column

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I'm trying to find how to replace text in the following format:

```
input1:input2:input3
aaa:bbb:ccc
111:222:333
```

I would like the result to look like:

```
input1:new-text:input3
aaa:new-text:ccc
111:new-text:333
```

It can be accomplished via sed, awk, cut or what ever as long as the result is good.

Comment: What have you tried? Googling `sed` would give you the answer very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the rule "replace the second field, delimited by colons with `new-text`", awk makes this fairly straight-forward:

```
awk -F':' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } {$2="new-text"; print} ' < input > output
```

The `-F':'` tells awk to use colons to separate fields within each line.

The `BEGIN` stanza sets the *output* field separator to the current field separator (colon), so that when we re-print the line later, awk joins the fields together with colons again.

The second section has no conditional in front of it, so it is executed for every line; it does the actual work of replacing the second field with `new-text`, then prints the new line.

Comment: Awesome!! Exactly what I wanted. Keeping this in my notes as a bash coder newbie :)

Comment: Glad it helped! Note that there's nothing "bash" about this!

Answer (score 0):

if you really need exactly the same text to replace middle chunk between the only surrounding pair of ':' on every line of file then this works

```
sed -i -- "s|:.*:|:${mynewtext}:|"   $inputfile
```

the pattern  .*  just means one or more characters

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your text is in file called `code`

```
]$cat code
input1:input2:input3
aaa:bbb:ccc
111:222:333
```

run this command

```
]$sed -e 's/:[^:]*:/:new-text:/' code
input1:new-text:input3
aaa:new-text:ccc
111:new-text:333
```

Answer (score 0):

To look at it in a generic and POSIX sed way, wherein the column to be removed can be supplied at the time of executing the `sed` code, as also the new contents of the column to be replaced also, you may do this:

```
n=2;             # the column number to be modified with a new value

repl="new-text"; # the text used to replace the contents of the n-th col

# to make the replacement sed friendly, otw, if it happened to have chars
# which have a meaning to sed when using on the rhs of s/// command, we will
# have an error on our hands.
repl_esc=$(printf '%s\n' "$repl" | sed -e 's|[\&/]|\\&|g;$!s/$/\\/')

sed -e '
    s/.*/:&:/
    '"s/:/\\n/$n;s//\\
/$n;
    s/\\n.*\\n/:${repl_esc}:/"'
    s/^://
    s/:$//
' input-file.txt
```